# iphone phonegap application

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In phone gap iphone application,I want to display local notification at regular interval.So how can I do that?I found one sample plugin of local notification but it not works, so is their any setting in property list file for display notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local notifications in iPhone, there is a PhoneGap plugin in the PhoneGap Plugins repo on GitHub: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

The local notification plugin is at:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/LocalNotification

It doesn't have a README, but it does have an example.

Comment: I downloaded that sample but in this PhoneGapLib.xcodeproj file is always missing.

Comment: Well, maybe the example was not very complete, but there us usage examples in the plugin's JavaScript file - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/LocalNotification/LocalNotification.js

Comment: Is there any permission we need to assign for that or need any changes in plist file of phonegap??? Because i do the same code but i don't able to show local notification.Is there any jquery we need to import?

Comment: Plugins have to be added to the PhoneGap.plist. In this case the Key is probably LocalNotification (and same for the Value) - http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43708792/How%20to%20Install%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS

Comment: <key>Plugins</key>
 <dict>
  <key>com.phonegap.notification</key>
  <string>PGNotification</string> <key>Notification</key>
  <string>Notification</string>
  <key>pushnotification</key>
  <string>PushNotification</string>
  <key>PushNotification</key>
  <string>PushNotification</string></dict> I use above lines in phonegap.plist file but it also not works.

Comment: In my project I also want to capture image on take a photo button click using camera of device.In that plug in i also not able to open camera device.So i think i am missing something common for all plugins.For camera i am using following code of github project           navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });

Comment: First, the key and string are probably both "LocalNotification" not PGNotification, or Notification or any combination including PushNotification... Second, have you added the .m and .h files to your Xcode project as per the wiki entry above? http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43708792/How%20to%20Install%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS

Answer (score 4):

I made this tutorial / example of how to use the localNotification as well as make a callback to your app...

http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=84

hope that helps!

Comment: Great nice tutorial ...Thank u so much

Comment: No problem! hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying what you're hoping to do. I don't think their's a built-in local/push notification in PhoneGap, but you can use the tools at http://urbanairship.com to accomplish this.

---

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to display a notification.

If that's what you're looking to do, stick this in your JS:

```
function alertDismissed(button) {
    if (button == 1) {
        alert('they hit yes');
    }
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'Look at this message now!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Look at me!',            // title
    'Yes,No'               // buttonName
);
```

You'll also need to make sure you're calling the phonegap.js file in your document head.

Comment: I want to display local notification like push notification.When application is close then also it will display alert view something like reminder app.

Comment: i know about urbanairship but i want to display local notification not push notification.